# How to select authenticated user data with PHP and AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, authentication

I have a problem that I've been trying to solve for a long time. I have read courses about PHP sessions and I had proposals to use localstorage but to no avail

The problem:

Im working with angularJS and PHP backend, and I have 2 views, one 'login.html' and the other 'info.html', 2 controllers (one for the login function and the other for selecting the user's data) . I managed to do the authentication phase but for the second step I want that when the user authenticates, it will be redirected to other view (info.html) where all the information of this user will be displayed. How can I store the data from login function and use it in the second controller(second web service)

**login.php**

```
<?php  
session_start();
$_SESSION['token'] = true;
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");  

 if(count($data) > 0)  

 { 

$Email=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->Email);
$mdp=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->mdp);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE (EmailClient = "'.$Email.'" AND   mdp= "'.$mdp.'")';

$q = mysqli_query($connect , $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0 )
  { 
       $token = md5($Email.time()."51395+81519851");
       $query = "UPDATE client SET token = '".$token."' WHERE EmailClient = '".$Email."'";
       mysqli_query($connect , $query);
       $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true; 
       $_SESSION["token"] = $token; 
       $_SESSION["Email"] = $Email; 
       $result['token'] = $token;           
       $resultstring=json_encode($result);
       $resultstring=str_replace("null", '""', $resultstring);
       echo $resultstring;
       exit;

  }

    ?>
```

**loginCtrl**

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $location,$state,$http,$window){

    $scope.submit = function()
    {
        data = {
            'Email' : $scope.Email,
            'password' : $scope.password
    };

        $http.post('http://localhost/deb/login.php', data)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config,result)
        {
            console.log(data);
            $state.go('info');

             }
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config, result)
        {      
            console.log('error');   
        });
    }

});
```

**infoCtrl :**

```
app.controller('infoCtrl', function($scope, $http,$state,$filter){

    $scope.loadColis = function(){ 
              $http.get("http://localhost/deb/info.php")  
           .success(function(data){  
                $scope.names = data;  
           });
      }
```

**info.php**

```
<?php  
session_start();
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");  

 $output = array();  
 $query = "SELECT Name,Adresse FROM client WHERE token = '".$_SESSION['token']."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
 {  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output[] = $row;  
      }  
      echo json_encode($output);  
 }  

 ?>
```

I don't know how get user authenticated data, how can I do please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello. Please take a look at http://bobby-tables.com and learn about SQL injection and how to prevent them. Actually your code is not safe at all.

Comment: Use session storage or cookies to access your authenticated data all over the application.

Comment: @Indhu, Can you give me an idea how can I do please!

Comment: @Twinfriends thank you, I m consulting you suggestion, I will manage this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Login Controller:

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $location,$state,$http,$window, $cookies){

    $scope.submit = function()
    {
        data = {
            'Email' : $scope.Email,
            'password' : $scope.password
    };

        $http.post('http://localhost/deb/login.php', data)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config,result)
        {
            console.log(data);
            $cookies.putObject('AuthenticateData', data);
            $state.go('info');

             }
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config, result)
        {      
            console.log('error');   
        });
    }

});
```

In Info controller:

```
app.controller('infoCtrl', function($scope, $http,$state,$filter, $cookies){
//use something like this
   var authenticateData =  cookies.getObject("AuthenticateData");
});
```

This is just an example to show how cookies does works. You can work around in it.

Comment: Thank you, I wish it can helps me to solve my problem. Thank you